# Reading Entire Files in MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

My project is to take a lot of data about dietary habits and use MapReduce (I plan on using two different MapReduces) to find out what top five foods correlate to a given feeling. A sample input file is as follows:

```
food parsnips  2017/1/24 7:00
food beef  2017/1/24 9:00
food oats  2017/1/24 12:00
feel sleepy  2017/1/24 16:00
food pineapple  2017/1/24 17:00
food squid  2017/1/25 7:00
feel sleepy  2017/1/25 11:00
food blueberries  2017/1/25 12:00
food plums  2017/1/25 14:00
feel headache  2017/1/25 18:00
food broccoli  2017/1/25 19:00
food strawberries  2017/1/26 6:00
feel tired  2017/1/26 6:00
food oats  2017/1/26 7:00
food celery  2017/1/26 8:00
food lobster  2017/1/26 9:00
food wings  2017/1/26 9:00
feel stomachache  2017/1/26 14:00
food fish  2017/1/26 16:00
food rice  2017/1/27 6:00
food barley  2017/1/27 11:00
food wings  2017/1/27 17:00
feel itchy  2017/1/27 18:00
food mustard  2017/1/27 19:00
food icecream  2017/1/28 6:00
feel sleepy  2017/1/28 6:00
food oats  2017/1/28 10:00
feel stomachache  2017/1/28 10:00
food grapes  2017/1/28 13:00
food cheese  2017/1/28 14:00
food bread  2017/1/28 15:00
feel itchy  2017/1/28 17:00
```

A given food is to be associated with a feeling up to twelve hours after the food is eaten. For example: in the first line, parsnips would have "sleepy" as a feeling associated with it, because the sleep feeling occurs 9 hours after the parsnips are eaten. If that 'sleepy' occurred at 18:00, then the parsnips would not be associated with sleepiness. There are many input files like this one.

This is my plan for the project:

1. The first MapReduce will read in the file and create (key, value) pairs where the key is "food, feeling," and the value is simply "one." In other words, it will create pairs where the key is just anytime a food correlates to a feeling. The reduce will then, like a Word Count, sum all of the times a given "food, feeling" occurs across all inputs.
2. The second MapReduce will take in the "food-feeling, sum" as its (key, value) pairs. It will then Map each feeling with all of the foods that cause it, resulting in a (key value) of "'feeling, food', x times." It will then reduce into an output a feeling's top five foods for causation, resulting in the following output:

"feeling1: food1, x incidents"

"feeling1: food2, x incidents"

My issue is that I don't know how to set up the first MapReduce function. I have read through much of the literature on MapReduce and have familiarized myself with the common MaxTemp and WordCount examples, but my issue is that I don't know how to take the 12-hour window and use the input file to create the "food-feeling, 1" key-value pairs. Any suggestions would be useful. I know that it has to do with the map function taking in the entire file text as a value rather than just an individual line's.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward way is to implement InputFormat of your own you can get an example from [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#fileformat).

The other way around is to implement one separate MapReduce program to pre-process the whole data. e.g. put the number of lines you want to the mapper should process in a single line e.g. Suppose you want to process the 5 lines by a mapper then do this

```
food parsnips  2017/1/24 7:00
food beef  2017/1/24 9:00
food oats  2017/1/24 12:00
feel sleepy  2017/1/24 16:00
food pineapple  2017/1/24 17:00
```

to something similar to this:

```
food parsnips  2017/1/24 7:00 | food beef  2017/1/24 9:00 | food oats 2017/1/24 12:00 | feel sleepy  2017/1/24 16:00 | food pineapple  2017/1/24 17:00
```

after that mapper will separate out the lines and process them.

The second approach is quite inefficient.